# Automatically generating DataGrid column from enum

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, enums

I'm using columns autogeneration feature of WPF `DataGrid` control. One of it's columns is a select column - based on some enum.

The enum looks like this:

```
public enum MyTypes {
  Integer = 1,
  Float = 2
  IntegerArray = 3,
  FloatArray = 4
}
```

I'd like to show the `array` types not as IntegerArray, FloatArray, but as Integer[], 
Float[] in the autogenerated dropdown list.

In other words - cell will contain a dropdown list with values Integer, Float, IntegerArray, FloatArray, and I want them to be Integer, Float, Integer[], Float[]. Obviously I can't change IntegerArray to Integer[] inside my MyTypes declaration.

How do I do that?

**EDIT:**

Pushpray's answer below works only partially - I get enum fields description (so instead of having FloatArr in the `ComboBox` I'm getting Float[], but when the column holding the`ComboBox` looses focus, then I get `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I don't follow. You want a different value displayed for your enum values? So the cell should contain the string 'Float[]' for example?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve. Cell will contain a dropdown list with values `Integer`, `Float`, `IntegerArray`, `FloatArray`, and I want them to be `Integer`, `Float`, `Integer[]`, `Float[]`. Obviously I can't change `IntegerArray` to `Integer[]` inside my `MyTypes` declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is how I offer to solve your issue

result

[image: result]

we will start by defining the desired values as `Description` attribute to the enum values

```
public enum MyTypes
{
    Integer = 1,
    Float = 2,
    [Description("Integer[]")]
    IntegerArray = 3,
    [Description("Float[]")]
    FloatArray = 4
}
```

then create a class with a method to enumerate the list from the enum type that will take Description attribute into account if applied

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    public class EnumHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetEnumDescriptions(Type enumType)
        {
            foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(enumType))
            {
                FieldInfo fi = enumType.GetField(item);

                DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
                    (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

                if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                    yield return attributes[0].Description;
                else
                    yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

finally use `ObjectDataProvider` to use the enumerator method `GetEnumDescriptions` in the class `EnumHelper`, and use the same as the source for the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`'s ItemsSource

sample xaml

```
<DataGrid xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="EnumValues" >
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                <Binding>
                    <Binding.Source>
                        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetEnumDescriptions"
                                            ObjectType="{x:Type l:EnumHelper}">
                            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                                <x:Type TypeName="l:MyTypes" />
                            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                        </ObjectDataProvider>
                    </Binding.Source>
                </Binding>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

**Using with Auto generating columns**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dGrid" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn"
          xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <l:EnumHelper x:Key="EnumHelper" />
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EnumValues"
                            MethodName="GetEnumDescriptions"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type l:EnumHelper}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="l:MyTypes" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTypesCellTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding EnumValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumHelper}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTypesCellEditingTemplate">
            <ComboBox  SelectedItem="{Binding EnumValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumHelper}}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumValues}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

event handler

```
    private void DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyType == typeof(MyTypes))
        {
            DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            templateColumn.Header = e.Column.Header;
            templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)dGrid.Resources["MyTypesCellTemplate"];
            templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate = (DataTemplate)dGrid.Resources["MyTypesCellEditingTemplate"];
            e.Column = templateColumn;
        }
    }
```

EnumHelper class

```
public class EnumHelper : IValueConverter
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetEnumDescriptions(Type enumType)
    {
        foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(enumType))
        {
            FieldInfo fi = enumType.GetField(item);

            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
                (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                yield return attributes[0].Description;
            else
                yield return item;
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;

        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return MyTypes.Float;

        Type enumType = typeof(MyTypes);
        foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(enumType))
        {
            FieldInfo fi = enumType.GetField(item);

            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
                (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0 && string.Equals(attributes[0].Description, value))
                return Enum.Parse(enumType, item);
        }
        return Enum.Parse(enumType, value.ToString());
    }
}
```

---

**Demo**

Here is a working sample code based on the answer above

[DataGridEnumsSample.zip](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2f5wPS0jKJPVGo1c2pHN29mSGc/view?pli=1) (VS 2013)

MD5 Checksum: `9C34BB81857C78375582FAC0E1C8A95D`

Comment: But my columns are autogenerated, so how can I make your mechanism work in my case? `Datagrid`'s `ItemsSource` property is bound to a `List<Class with informations about columns, and one of those is Enum>`

Comment: you may perhaps define data template for the same and customize it while column generation see [How to: Customize Auto-Generated Columns in the DataGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950)

Comment: Ok, I'll try it later, and accept your answer if it will work

Comment: Just now I returned to this project, and something bad is happening - I can select value off the combo box, but when field holding the combo box looses focus, instantly I get exception - `NullReferenceException` as if no value is set

Comment: If you find it difficult to merge this solution to your project. What you can do is to create new test project with the solution above and see how it works, then it would be easier for you to merge with your project. I am sure you are not missing any big thing here.

Comment: Could you at least explain me where this `EnumValue` comes from?

Comment: in the example in the answer `EnumValue` is a property in my test VM. in your case it should be one of your property in the collection bound to DataGrid, assuming of type `MyTypes` as mentioned in the question.

Comment: I have prepared a sample for you based on the answer above, you may please download [DataGridEnumsSample.zip](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2f5wPS0jKJPVGo1c2pHN29mSGc/view?pli=1) and try the same.

Comment: Thanks again - actually one thing that was in the way was this EnumValue - I copied your code into my project without changing this so it didn't work :). SO is telling me that I can award you with a bounty in 1 hour.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you, I was sure that you are not missing any big thing. Anyways happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution that will allow you to display enums in a `DataGrid` using auto-generated columns. This works for enum types that are created using reflection.

First, create an `EnumTemplateColumn` that inherits from `DataGridBoundColumn`:

```
public class EnumTemplateColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
{
    private readonly Type enumType;

    public EnumTemplateColumn(Type enumType)
    {
        this.enumType = enumType;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        string columnHeader = cell.Column.Header.ToString();
        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
        var dataRowView = (DataRowView) dataItem;
        var enumValue = dataRowView[columnHeader];

        textBlock.Text = Enum.GetName(this.enumType, enumValue);

        return textBlock;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Next, use the `OnAutoGeneratingColumn` event of the `DataGrid` to use the `EnumTemplateColumn`:

```
    private void DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            e.Column = new EnumTemplateColumn(e.PropertyType)
            {
                Header = e.Column.Header,
            };
        }
    }
```

And the WPF component:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
              Grid.Row="5" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataTable}" IsReadOnly="True"
              AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it: in the `AutoGeneratingColumn`event of the `DataGrid`, replace the default `DataGridComboBoxColumn` by `DataGridTextColumn`, and add the binding and converter manually.

```
    private void dataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            //(e.Column as DataGridComboBoxColumn)

            var col = new DataGridTextColumn
            {
                Header = e.PropertyName
            };

            col.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName)
            {
                Converter = new WPFCommon.BindingConverters.EnumConverter()
            };

            // Replace the auto-generated column with the new one.
            e.Column = col;
        }
    }
```

The converter class,

```
namespace WPFCommon.BindingConverters
{
    public class EnumConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        //** this does not work for enum value in DataTable
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            return ((Enum)value).GetDescription();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

The class for enum extension,

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enu)
    {
        DisplayAttribute attr = GetDisplayAttribute(enu);
        return attr != null ? attr.Name : enu.ToString();
    }

    public static string GetDescription(this Enum enu)
    {
        DescriptionAttribute attr = GetDescriptionAttribute(enu);
        return attr != null ? attr.Description : enu.ToString();
    }

    private static DescriptionAttribute GetDescriptionAttribute(object value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} is not an enum", type));
        }

        // Get the enum field.
        var field = type.GetField(value.ToString());
        return field == null ? null : field.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>();
    }

    private static DisplayAttribute GetDisplayAttribute(object value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} is not an enum", type));
        }

        // Get the enum field.
        var field = type.GetField(value.ToString());
        return field == null ? null : field.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
    }
}
```